# Android: Intent createChooser not working properly

Tags: android, android-intent

I am adding share feature in the app. Below is my code:

```
public static void shareData(String title, String message, Uri imageUri, Activity activity) {
    try {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, message);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            Logger.errorMessage(ShareUtil.class.getSimpleName(), "share if");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            sendIntent.setType("image/*");
        } else {
            Logger.errorMessage(ShareUtil.class.getSimpleName(), "share else");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        }
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share using"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "No App found to share", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is showing the list of apps, but when I select any app, the title and message is not sent. I am not getting what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT` is mainly used in email. Try replacing it with `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`. This works in most apps.

Comment: Hi, I have one query. I have to share the data alongwith image. As you have seen in my code above, I am passing image uri. The image is loaded from the url. So in order to do so, I have to download the image first. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there is a better way.